# WooCommerce Extension - redirect user in gateway callback handler

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

The WooCommerce API Callback documentation says:

> WooCommerce will exit after that action, but you can still redirect the user elsewhere from your handler if you wish.

[Documentation Reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/wc_api-the-woocommerce-api-callback/#section-2)

In my gateway callback handler:

```
function handle_callback() {
  // business logic that gets the necessary $order object
  $order->payment_complete();
  wp_redirect( $this->get_return_url( $order ) ) // no observable effect
  exit;
}
```

Hooking into the WooCommerce Callback:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_api_my_plugin_id', array( &$this, 'handle_callback' ) );
```

Does anyone know how to properly redirect a user from within the callback handler?

**Edit**: added `exit;` right after the redirect instruction.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, the question is updated.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, nope. My `business logic` comment encapsulates everything leading up to the point of redirection but that's beyond the scope of the question. My only concern is the redirection is not quite working in my scenario.

Comment: I've updated the question accordingly. Apologies for leaving that out.

Answer (score 0):

; add semi colon in the end of second last line

wp_redirect( $this->get_return_url( $order ) ); // no observable effect